# How to take value in JavaScript in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, node.js

I defined javascript tag in Asp.Net now I want to take values from textbox you can check my source code below can you tell me how to take those var values in script

```
var addr = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox3.ClientID%>').value;
var dt = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').value;
var amnt = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value;

const payment = {
  source: {
      address: address,
      maxAmount: {
      value: '0.01',
      currency: 'XRP'
    }
  },

  destination: {
      address: 'rDe3wB5oUairVejDiqCg8p2hc7ExPpNmFs',
      tag: 8779,
      amount: {
      value: '50',
      currency: 'XRP'
    }
  }
}
```

I just want to take var addr in address and dt in destination tag and amnt in value. I defined  tag in ASP.NET

Comment: Take var values in which script? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: you can use ajax.

Comment: my problem is almost solved solution was i defines two single quotes variables like addr and amnt in const now only one problem is remaining it is tag it need integer value what should i do for that? var dt = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').value; i defined this and after then parseint(dt); but it is also not working it need this value example : tag: 5654, "5654 is integer value without single or double quote."

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're asking is how to use the variables you've defined in your object?  If so, then have you tried this?  it should work fine...

```
const payment = {
  source: {
      address: addr,
      maxAmount: {
      value: '0.01',
      currency: 'XRP'
    }
  },

  destination: {
      address: addr,
      /* use parseInt function to convert string value to an int */
      tag: parseInt(dt),
      amount: {
      value: amnt,
      currency: 'XRP'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But two values are in single quotes and tag is integer value .This way it is not working

Comment: Ah ok, so you want to convert one to an int.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @Jitender: the values from the Text boxes are strings, so in constructing your object there's no difference in the structure of the object when using  a *string variable* vs a *hard coded string* really, so those are fine.  The one which you require to be an INT needs to be converted from a string into an int, which the parseInt() function can do (see the edited example above).  Do bear in mind that this isn't checking that the user has entered a valid number though - if you entered a non-integer value it'll return NaN which may cause you problems.

Comment: my problem is almost solved solution was i defines two single quotes variables like addr and amnt in const now only one problem is remaining it is tag it need integer value what should i do for that?

Comment: var dt = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').value; i defined this and after then parseint(dt); but it is also not working it need this value example : tag: 5654,    "5654  is integer value without single or double quote."

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'not working' - what actual error do you have.  Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating this working https://jsfiddle.net/dqtpjnwc/14/

Comment: i need tag :  in integer value in above source

Comment: var dt = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').value; ---------------------tag:  parseInt(dt) ,---------i am getting error because of this i am doing something wrong there

Comment: what is the error?   assuming you have a valid integer value in the HTML `input` element with the `id` which you're pointing it at, the code should work. did you look at the jsfiddle link I posted?

Comment: its not an error its just this js is not working if i am mannually giving "tag : 56565" then it is working successfully you can see it is an integer value

Comment: are you expecting to see the int value there when you view the final html page generated by ASP.Net?  Because you won't.  it's a javascript variable/function.  It'll evaluate it when it runs on the client and constructs your `payment` object - you should never be able to 'see' the value if viewing the generated source code, because it will change depending on what the user enters in the `TextBox2` control (which will actually be an HTML `input` control on the page)

Comment: what do you mean by "working".  how are you verifying that it "works" when you type a constant int value?.  What are you expecting to see?  Is there a later function which is using this `payment` object which is finding the `tag` property is not set correctly? show the code which actually gives an error.  If there is no code then how can you tell whether it is working or not?

Comment: working means transaction sucessfully initiated.what i want bro try to understand "tag : 56565" this form is working fine if i am parsing it to int like var dt; and parint(dt) it doesnt work .

Comment: How are you verifying this?  All the code you've presented does is creates a javascript object with hard coded values.  I've given you a version that instead of these hard coded values uses variables populated from the values of some html input elements.  It still creates an object which is structurally the same as in your initial example.  What is done with the object afterwards?  I don't have any idea what a *transaction* is in this context because you haven't supplied any further information.

Comment: this is nodejs javascript

Comment: whether node.js is involved or not doesn't make any difference (though this sample looks like ASP.Net WebForms so is going to ultimately run in a browser).  if you cannot show the code which is actually *doing* things with the object constructed in your code, which "works" when you don't use a variable, and show how it "doesn't work" when you *do* use a variable, then I cannot help.  I cannot see any problem with this code

Comment: here is a modified jsfiddle.  This creates an object with fixed values and one with variables, then uses JSON.stringify() and alert() to pop up messages to show how each object looks.  They look exactly the same apart from the dynamic one using the value from the input box.  https://jsfiddle.net/dqtpjnwc/25/

Comment: in case it's not clear, to run the jsfiddle example push the RUN button (top-left of the page) then in the bottom-right window (which shows the output) click the button.  this will run the javascript at the bottom-left and produce the output.